# Invertible sheaf such that for any point there exists a global section not vanishing at that point

Tags: algebraic-geometry, quasicoherent-sheaves

Let $\mathcal{L}$ be an invertible sheaf on a quasicompact scheme $X$. I want to prove that there exists an epimorphism $\mathcal{O}_{X}^{\oplus I}\rightarrow\mathcal{L}$ if and only if for any point $p\in X$ there exists a global section of $\mathcal{L}$ not vanishing at $p$.

In the page 121 of Hartshorne's book it is claimed that if there exists an epimorphism $\mathcal{O}_{X}^{\oplus I}\rightarrow\mathcal{L}$  then there exists a family of global sections $\{s_{i}\}_{i\in I}$ of $\mathcal{L}$ such that $\mathcal{L}_{p}$ is generated by $\{s_{i,p}\}_{i\in I}$ as $\mathcal{O}_{X,p}$-module for every $p\in X$.

The first implication easily follows from this fact, but I am not able to prove the fact, nor the other implication.

Comment: In your second paragraph, you have $\mathcal{F}$ when I think you mean $\mathcal{L}$.

Comment: I assume that $l$ is finite. Then, this is true only with some assumptions on $X$, for example, Noetherian. The disjoint union of infinitely many points will give you a counterexample otherwise.

Comment: @Stahl Thank you, I have edited it.

Comment: @Mohan Thank you, I think that if $X$ is quasicompact then we may assume $I$ to be finite. I add this hypothesis to the statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be quasi-compact is enough, but I will assume Noetherian for one direction.

If you had $\mathcal{O}_X^l\to \mathcal{L}$ a surjection and $p$ any point, we have a surjection $\mathcal{O}_{X,p}\to\mathcal{L}_p$ is onto. But the latter is a one dimensional vector space over $k(p)$ and thus at least one of the sections from $\mathcal{O}_X^l$ must be non-zero at $p$ proving the result in one direction.

For the reverse direction, if $p$ is any point, you have a section not vanishing at $p$ and then this section will not vanish at any point in a neighbourhood of $p$. Now, take any point outside this open set and then exactly as before, we have a section not vanishing in a neighbourhood of this point. So, these two sections together do not vanish at any point in the union of these two open sets. Now, I hope you see how Noetherianness would give you finitely  many sections, which together do not vanish at any point. This implies there is a surjection as desired, since $\mathcal{L}$ is invertible, so locally one generated.

Comment: Dear Mohan, from the first part it follows that there exists a rational section of $\mathcal{O}_{X}^{l}$ that does not vanish at $p$. Does it imply that there exists a global section of $\mathcal{L}$ not vanishing at $p$?

Comment: Why rational section? We are only dealing with global sections.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but the fact that $\mathcal{O}_{X,p}\rightarrow \mathcal{L}_{p}$ is surjective means that there exist an open neighborhood $U$ of $p$ and a section $s\in\Gamma(U,\mathcal{O}_{X})$ such that the image of $(U,s)\in \mathcal{O}_{X,p}$ in $\mathcal{L}_{p}$ is not in the maximal ideal of this local ring. How do we know that we may take $U$ to be $X$?

Comment: In general this is correct, but we are starting with a global map $\mathcal{O}_X^l\mathcal{L}$ and looking at the induced map at $p$, so we are not dealing with open sets $U$ etc.

Comment: Why is Noetherianness needed for this argument?